# Having two selects statements in one

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have looked inside other threads same as mine, but they didn't seem to answer my question.

I have this code here:

```
select * from outerbarcodes where not exists (select 1
              from bridgebarcodes
              where bridgebarcodes.barcode = outerbarcodes.barcode
             )
             union SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size, barcode FROM outerbarcodes WHERE
COALESCE(productcode, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(Brand, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(product, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(size, '') <> ''
```

I don't understand why the`UNION` isn't working?

This is my column set up:

**Table: bridgebarcodes**
Columns:
ID int(11) AI PK 
ProductCode varchar(100) 
Barcode varchar(100)

**Table: outerbarcodes**
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
ProductCode varchar(100) 
Brand varchar(100) 
Product varchar(100) 
size varchar(100) 
Barcode varchar(100)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the first select is select * so it'll include the column called id but the second select returns only a subset of the columns. You hace to union similar sets.

Comment: Like this you mean? `select ProductCode, barcode
from outerbarcodes
where not exists (select 1
                  from bridgebarcodes
                  where bridgebarcodes.barcode = outerbarcodes.barcode
                 )
                 union
 SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size, barcode
FROM outerbarcodes
WHERE
    COALESCE(productcode, '') <> '' AND
    COALESCE(Brand, '') <> '' AND
    COALESCE(product, '') <> '' AND
    COALESCE(size, '') <> ''`

Comment: do not share image share text code

Comment: your two selects have to have the same columns to work in a union

Comment: How would I amend the code? Im trying to remove all rows that have a null value and show all values that dont exist based on two tables

Comment: what error do you get? you just say " the UNION isn't working"

Comment: ERROR CODE: 1222 ive sorted it now. I have created a new table based on this code: `SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size, barcode FROM outerbarcodes WHERE
COALESCE(productcode, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(Brand, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(product, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(size, '') <> ''` then ran this code here: `select * from outerbarcodes where not exists (select 1
              from bridgebarcodes
              where bridgebarcodes.barcode = outerbarcodes.barcode
             )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 queries of the UNION must have the same number of columns and the columns must be of the same data type, so change to this:

```
select productcode, Brand, product, size, barcode from outerbarcodes where not exists (select 1
              from bridgebarcodes
              where bridgebarcodes.barcode = outerbarcodes.barcode
             )
             union SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size, barcode FROM outerbarcodes WHERE
COALESCE(productcode, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(Brand, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(product, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(size, '') <> ''
```